# How Visual Studio for Mac is communicating to XCODE?

Tags: .net, xamarin, mono, monodevelop

For example, when you are making the outlets in XCODE and then open the VSmac there is the reference of the outlet already and you can use it.

I know that VSmac is using Mono for that but for me, it's very misunderstanding, how XCODE can make references in VSmac and how this two big software is communicating to each other.

The reason for this question is that I want to deeply understand in MONO and Xamarin, how they are doing their jobs. Because I want to become Core Xamarin developer and make some contributions, and every little help will be great for me and you will be welcomed!

And also I think there will be great if JetBrains Rider and VScode will have the features VSmac has.

Is there some way to Add this kind of thing to Visual studio code?
If no, why?
If yes, how?

Is there some way to Add this kind of thing to JetBrains Rider?
If no, why?
If yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Apple has no public API to their Xcode IDE, so Xamarin does it the old-fashion way and creates a temporary Xcode project (`.xcodeproj`) based upon the state of your current `Xamarin.iOS` project and then launches Xcode with that temp project, they use a file watcher on those xcode project files and when you save/new a file in Xcode, Xamarin sees the change, parses the ObjC `.h` and creates matching "outlets" and "actions" in the generated partial C# classes. No reason it could not be added to VSC or Rider, but this integration is not open-source, so you would need to write it from scratch.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you very much. Maybe add this answer in the answers section and not to the comments section. Thank you!